# Heroku Redis Cloud : TypeError: Cannot read property 'language' of undefined

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); 
var session = require('express-session');  
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
app.use(cookieParser(SecretKey)); 
app.use( bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

var redisURL = url.parse(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL);
app.use(session({
             store: new RedisStore({ url: redisURL.hostname , port: redisURL.port, client: redis }), 
             secret: SecretKey,
             resave: true,
             saveUninitialized: true,
             key: 'sid',
             cookie: { 
                        secure: false,  
                        httpOnly: false, 
                     }  
            })
  );

//this part below is actually later down in the code so the req variable does exist
if (req.session.language) {console.log(1);}
else {console.log(0)};
```

It seems correct and my code works when I run redis server locally but I don't understand why its not connecting to Heroku Redis Cloud. It should have something to do with the setup code. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is this all your code? There is no `session_var`. Can you post the whole error?

Comment: @ishegg I updated it, it seems like req.session doesn't exist at all

Comment: It looks like you're pasting code from several scripts. There is no `req` variable in your script, amongst several other issues. The most concerning to me is that there is no `session_var`, so why is it complaining about it? What line number does it show as the culprit on the error?

Comment: Please read the comment (this part is later in the code but the req variable does exist). And by session_var I meant a session variable. I updated to the actually variable I am using. My code works with localhost redis, so the issue is not what u r saying